# good way to let users search their friends on my fb app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to let my users search(not browse) their friend on my fb app. What is the best way?

I have surveyed this issue for hours. I got two ways:

1. use Graph API:

   https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...

by this way, I can get the friends of user as json, and by parsing the json, I can get the one who is the user's target.

However, there are two issues.

First, user need to input the exact name of his/her friend. For example, my app can't find "Steve Jobs" with "Steve" by parsing json.

Second, if the user has a lot of friends, the cost of parsing json may be terrible.

2.
use the searching api:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user

by this way, user can get "Steve Jobs" with "steve". However, it is obvious that users may find someone who is not their friend.

I think neither of these ways are ideal enough. Any suggestion?

Thank you sincerely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: Request dialogs
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

--

For Search Partially, may use indexOf function to check whether this string is match

Comment: request dialog is not what I need, but the suggestion of using index function is useful. thank you anyways.